# Scanning and replacing values inside nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How to compare and replace keys inside nested dictionaries according to what user inputs

Comment: both keys and values?

Comment: Yes. Key name is same just values are change so should overwrite

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: @user3236912 The structure of dict is consistent or is it arbitrarily nested?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary its consistent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dic = {'Sally':['1346','A','April', {'1346': ('week', 6)}],
       'Annie': ['1347', 'A', 'April', {'1346': ('week', 5)}],
       'Marie': ['0', 'Absent', 'Fall', {}]}

for value in dic.values():
    for element in value:
         if isinstance(element, dict) and '1346' in element:
             element['1346'] = ('month',6)
```

if this were Python 2, I would use `dic.itervalues()` instead of `dic.values()`.

And here's the results:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(dic)
{'Annie': ['1347', 'A', 'April', {'1346': ('month', 6)}],
 'Marie': ['0', 'Absent', 'Fall', {}],
 'Sally': ['1346', 'A', 'April', {'1346': ('month', 6)}]}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I check for condition just before replacing.

Comment: Forexample, just before replacing I want to check if 2nd value of tuple associated with a key is less than 9 only then replace otherwise delete the whole key and assoicated value from nested dictionary

Comment: So to do that, instead of immediately assigning the element dict value to the key, you'd do that check on the element dict. e.g. ``if element[1346][1] > 9: del element['1346']``, else: do the assignment.

Comment: Ok, I will post shortly. And in above solution is it 1346 or '1346'?e.g.if element[1346][1] > 9: del element['1346']

Comment: It's fairly standard to use integers and not string representations of integers, but that's up to you. Yeah, I used an integer and that should have been a string, '1346'.